# Implementing native-like time picker on Blackberry with mobiscroll

Tags: html, blackberry, time, picker, mobiscroll

I have a web application which has a text box for entering time in hh:mm:tt format. A time picker has been integrated using [mobiscroll](http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/)
I am having issues while trying to enter time using the Blackberry browser. I have tried the following:

1. Tried to use the clickpick option in mobiscroll but the buttons do not get clicked using the mouse pointer in BB non touch devices.
2. Tried to implement the native HTML time control. It seemed to work fine on most devices but it does not work on BB Bold 9700
3. Tried [datebox](https://github.com/jtsage/jquery-mobile-datebox) plugin but could not get it to work, plus it is very slow.

I am running out of options, could anyone please answer the following questions:

a. Is it possible to call the BB native time picker control in a webapp ?

b. Can a BB webworks component be used in a webapp ?

c. Is there any way to make the HTML time input control work on BB Bold 9700

Appreciate your help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest release [2.0.3](http://download.mobiscroll.com) 
Issues with BB were fixed.